# Is it possible to load a class without loading referenced classes/imports?

Tags: java, dependencies, classloader, circular-dependency, dynamic-class-loaders

(Yes, this is hacky and probably not best practice, but it is the least bulky solution)

I have a project that involves several jars - a runnable launcher, a server, a wrapper for the server, and plugins for the server.

The launcher runs the wrapper by starting a new unconnected process, a child process, or just by instantiating it, depending on config. This should be unimportant with regards to the issue.

The wrapper uses URLClassLoader to load the server jar and start it, which works fine.

Before starting the server, the wrapper looks for plugins that contain certain classpaths/files normally used in the server, and loads them, patching the normal version of the class.

The problem is that the classloader wants to automatically resolve every class and import in the plugin patch classfiles, and the server has not been loaded yet.

I need to either prevent the classloader from resolving imports, or load the classes after the server and replace the already-loaded classes with them. As far as i know the second option is impossible without instability and bytecode manipulation?

Comment: Just to be clear about your problem, when you say *"The problem is that the classloader wants to automatically resolve every class and import in the plugin patch classfiles, and the server has not been loaded yet."*, this means that the plugin patches have dependencies on server classes and so the class loader loads the server as a result of loading the plugins, but you don't want it to load the server yet, because this screws up your whole patching system, correct?

Comment: Also this sounds like a mess; there were certainly better approaches that could have been taken from the start, is it too late / not possible to redesign it a bit?

Comment: Close, but it is not able to load the server at that point, so it just throws a ClassNotFoundException.

And redesign it in what way? There is really no simpler alternative.

Comment: Can you clarify your question to describe how exactly you're patching the server class and what you mean by "plugin", so nobody else interprets it the same way I did? Also how you're applying the patches may open up some new options / limit some existing options.

Comment: Are you looking for [`ClassLoader.loadClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass-java.lang.String-boolean-) with a `resolve` argument of `false`?

Comment: @EJP Heh, I added that to my answer at the same time; I wonder if that's all the OP's asking for, after all that effort...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, answering your title question:

> Is it possible to load a class without loading referenced classes/imports?

Well you could choose not to *resolve* the class by passing false to [`loadClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String,%20boolean)). Details about what resolving a class entails can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.3.3). You could then do the resolution in a separate step by calling [`resolveClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#resolveClass(java.lang.Class)) explicitly.

---

However, if that doesn't get you what you want, I don't know if this is the only possible solution, and it's certainly awful (and there were definitely better ways to approach this from the start), but what if you do something like this:

I'm going to call your classes that serve as patches and must be loaded before the server "pre-load" classes / code. I'm going to call the components of your patches that have server dependencies but whose loading must be delayed until after the server loads "post-load" classes / code.

For each of your plugins:

1. Strip all the post-load stuff out of the patch class and move it to a different class, e.g. `PluginImplementation` or something. Then make an instance of that implementation class be a member of your plugin class, delegating any necessary member functions to it, *but do not instantiate a `PluginImplementation` right off the bat, and make the member field be of type `Object` (this is often described as [an opaque pointer / the pimpl pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer))*. Essentially you're refactoring to use the pimpl idiom, where your pre-load stuff is coded directly, and your post-load stuff is actually delegated to a different class hidden behind an `Object` and not initialized immediately. **Your goal is to remove all dependencies on server classes from the plugin class itself, changing it to be the *bare minimum* necessary for the patch to just be *loaded*, but moving all the meat to an implementation class ultimately hidden behind an opaque pointer.**
2. Now load all of your plugins as normal. They should load now, and since all the post-load stuff that has server dependencies has been removed from them, the server classes won't be loaded.
3. *Now* have your plugins expose some sort of `serverLoaded()`, or `initializePlugin()` method or something like that. *After* the server class loads, go through and call these on each loaded plugin.
4. Finally, in the initialization method from the previous step, have your plugin instantiate the post-load classes *using `Class.forName().newInstance()`*.

So, basically, you hide all your post-load stuff behind an opaque pointer, thus keeping it hidden from the class loader, then when it's time, you dynamically instantiate the various `PluginImplementation` classes, thus making your plugins "fully complete" but allowing the server-dependent parts to be delay loaded.

The downside is this adds a few limitations and requires a lot of care. You need to make sure that none of your `PluginImplementation`-delegated methods are called until after the server loads and the initialization functions are called, because the implementation classes won't have been instantiated yet.

I am sure there may be better options but this is the one I could think of that probably involves the *least* amount of work given what you already have. You'll have to move a lot of code around; an IDE like Eclipse or whatever can make spitting out delegates easy at least (just temporarily make the member field be a `PluginImplementation` to help the IDE along then you can change it back to `Object` after you generate all the code), but it should minimize *fundamental * changes to your existing architecture.

---

Here's another idea, although I'm not sure how well it fits in with your current code, or if it's even possible in your situation:

Basically, the goal here is to just **make the plugins no longer be dependent on the server itself**, by doing the following:

1. Declare your server as an *interface*.
2. Make your concrete server implementation implement that interface.
3. Change all plugins to operate on that interface instead of on an instance of the server class itself.
4. Make sure your server class doesn't declare any inner classes that the plugins may use: Break any inner classes out into the top level (IDE's like Eclipse can do this for you).

Now you'll have to figure out a way to tell each plugin the instance of the server it's working with, but the plugin will store this in a member with the type of the base interface.

This way, loading the plugins won't load the server itself, only the base interface.

I think this idea is a hell of a lot simpler and less hackier than the above, I just don't know if it's more or less feasible than the above.

---

Note that both of these options don't necessarily [guarantee success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487888/is-java-class-loader-guaranteed-to-not-load-classes-that-arent-used), but in practice they'll probably work.

Comment: A very detailed answer, but you missed the entire point of what i am trying to do. The patches being loaded are _patches_, not dynamic plugins for an API. The main body of the plugins are loaded post-server.

How would the "PluginImplmentation" get loaded before the server class it has to replace? It cant.

Comment: @confusedpenguin Oh, but you described them as "plugins". I've added a second option, and redesigning it to be a dynamic plugin API is one of the redesign options that you asked about in a question comment. But this second option still goes with the dynamic plugin theme. Do you think you could clarify your question to describe how exactly you're patching the server class and what you mean by "plugin"?

Comment: I have already explained it as simply as possible, and am just going to wait and ask an expert, since nobody seems to be fully comprehending the problem.

It is as simple as _I need to either prevent the classloader from resolving imports, or load the classes after the server and replace the already-loaded classes with them._
I guess i have learned not to provide any details, and only ask a straight question if i want an answer.

TL;DR If i wanted to reverse-engineer millions of lines of code to fix something this simple, i would not be asking for help here.

Comment: @confusedpenguin It's because you didn't explain it well; there's a lot of skill on this site, if "nobody" fully comprehends it, it could be on you! I mean that constructively. :) Anyways; if `loadClass(..., false)` doesn't solve your problem then you're SOL and you *have* to refactor. Experts will give you better solutions, not always the simplest, because they've been around the block. Imagine how much less trouble you'd be having now if you e.g. gave more details then got more than a simple straight answer to your other question about patching classes. :)

Comment: **protected Class<?> loadClass(String name,boolean resolve)  ?**
See, i was not even aware this existed, it does not show up in my IDE and i have not seen it used in any classloader tutorials. That is probably all i need to make this work, thank you.

spending years answering tech questions myself, i have found that it is always best to assume the person asking the question has no idea what they are doing and did not try the obvious solution.

Comment: @confusedpenguin It doesn't show up because it is protected. You'd have to subclass e.g. `URLClassLoader` to implement the logic you need; it still could be tricky. It's actually one of the *weirder* solutions (if it actually solves your issue without adding additional problems), IMO. It's worth a shot though.